# Parent Fields pre-populate after selection of related object record type

Tags: urlhacking

I have Parent object (A) master detail relation with another custom object (B).

**Requirement:**

When i click on New button on related list page (B) based on 'B' object record type, system has to prepopuate few field values on child record (edit page layout)

There are multiple 'B' object record type are available, i want to prepopulate only for certain record type

**For Example:**

- After clicking 'New' button on related list select B1 record type then prepopulate parent fields but when user selects B2 record type, system should not prepopulate the values.

Is this scenario possible using 'URL Hacking' ? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

- I had very similar scenario, and I was able to pass values for Standard fields through URL hacking (I remember passing DOM Id of the standard InputField in Edit Form as params)

  ```
  https://mydomain.salesforce.com/001/e?acc2=karthikselva
  ```

[image]
 This will open a new Account page and set **Account Name** field as `karthikselva`. Similarly find the first 3 characters of your child Object **B** and **inspect the DOM** to find the **name** of all the fields in form as I did.

```
    https://mydomain.salesforce.com/XXX/e?fieldname=karthikselva
```

- But custom fields had weird and dynamic DOM Id formats (which might cause lots of trouble if you have managed package code working with multiple orgs). So the hard coding of params doesn't work so good as it usually works for Reports as `?pv0`, finally this is what I ended up doing.

**Step 1:** Create an Apex extension Controller for Child object **CreateBFromA** which in constructor receives the Parent Object **A's** Id from URL and sets the field for the **new** Child object **B** only if the RecordTypeId matches.

**Psuedocode:**

```
Id aId = ApexPage.getParameters.get('aId');
A a = [Select field1,field2 .. fieldn,RecordTypeId from A where Id = :aId];            
B b = new B();
if(a.RecordTypeId == MY_RECORD_TYPE_ID) {
  b.field1 = a.field1;
  b.field2 = a.field2;
  b.fieldn = a.fieldn;
}
```

**Step 2:** Create an VisualForce page with form for the fields you want to save in child Object **B** and set the standardController as above **B** and extension as above controller **CreateBFromA**.

**Step 3:** Create custom button and pass the /apex/createBFromA?object_id={!sObject.Id} as parameter to the button for the master object

```
  /apex/createBFromA?aId={a.Id}
```

**Step 4:** Drag and drop the custom button in your Master object **A**

The above approach is much cleaner, extensible and doesn't rely on any URL hacking (URL hacking might break in lightning components which is considered to be future of Salesforce UI).

Comment: Thanks Karthik. Before visualforce page, if possible can we try 'URL hacking' method? since we are not using lightining / reports for this functionality. And i need to this solution as early as possbile. please suggest..

Comment: I have updated the answer with URL hacking I did. Please let me know if that is helpful

Comment: Karthik, can you please update your answer (URL hacking method) - i am not able to see the updates.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot as well at beginning of my answer

Comment: Hi Karthik, is that possible to add inline visualforce page for this requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work lightning this solution will only work for classic, you need to create a lightning app to achieve this with a init method